# How to Use Count Down in Javascript Using A String Length stored in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, countdown

```
    var allQuestionsArray = ["question1 asffdsdsfd","question2 asdffffsd","question3 asddda","question ajsdjj 4"];
    var loop = [];
    $.each(allQuestionsArray, function (index, key) {
    loop = key.length;
    timeOut(loop);

    setTimeout(function () {
      $(#question-' + index + '-section').fadeOut(),
      $('#question-' + index + '-section').fadeIn();
    }, (loop * 1000));
});

function startTimer(duration, display) {
                    console.log(duration);
                    var start = Date.now(),
                        diff,
                        minutes,
                        seconds;
                    function timer() {
                        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
                        // startTimer() was called
                        if(duration <= 0){

                            display.textContent = "00:00";
                        }else{
                        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
                        //console.log(diff);

                        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float

                        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
                        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

                        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                        if (diff <= 0) {
                            start = Date.now() + 1000;
                        }
                        }
                    };

                    timer();
                    setInterval(timer, 1000);
                }
                function timeOut(limit) {

                    display = document.querySelector('#time');
                    startTimer(limit, display);

                }
```

1- What I am expecting from this code it should generate a countdown and needs to hideout all questions section except one it should work till the loop completed.

2- I want my code take the length of every string stored in the array and assign it to the timer == "timeOut(string.length)" that's what my mean.

3- The problem is when the code executes the timer starts according to the length of last string "question ajsdjj 4" doesn't start from the first string of the array.

I want to start the timer from first string of the array when the timer completes then it has to move to second string of the array and so on.

Comment: `setTimeout` executes the passed function asynchronously, i.e. it doesn't block the current function until the callback is executed. Omit the loop, and call a new timeout in the callback function instead.

Comment: @Teemu How I can do that can you please explain it?